# Redirect to page depending on domain language

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am really a noob when it comes to PHP and I would like to ask for your help. I would like to create a 404.php for my Wordpress site that shows the 404 page in the appropriate language. The site is multilingual: Dutch and English. (I tried some plugins but they don't work with my current theme). I have done some research and found some bits and pieces and mastered a piece of php code that doesn't work. If you could be so kind to point me in the right direction, that would be great. This is what I came up with:

```
<?php
$incomingUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($incomingUrl == 'damcms.com/en') {
  wp_redirect(damcms.com/en/page-not-found-404);
  exit;
} else {
  wp_redirect(damcms.com/pagina-niet-gevonden-404);
  exit;
}
?>
```

I don't get an error message, nothing is being shown. So I miss something, what?Thanks in advance.
Claudia

Comment: Inside the  `wp_redirect()`, are they strings? You should quote strings.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason nothing happens is here:

```
wp_redirect(damcms.com/en/page-not-found-404);
```

Any time you have a string in PHP it ***must*** be in quotes; otherwise PHP tries to interpret it as instructions (and `damcms.com/en/page-not-found-404` is not a valid PHP instruction).

So this would work:

```
wp_redirect('damcms.com/en/page-not-found-404');
```

But there's a bigger issue: you don't want to just check if the URL is ***exactly*** `damcms.com/en` — you want to check if it ***starts with*** `damcms.com/en`.

So, perhaps this:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'damcms.com/en') !== false)) {
  wp_redirect('damcms.com/en/page-not-found-404');
} else {
  wp_redirect('damcms.com/pagina-niet-gevonden-404');
}
exit;
```

But going one level deeper, even this is a little iffy. WordPress already has a `404.php` template that shows for any 404 page. I strongly recommend editing that — and ***there*** do the `if ... 'damcms.com/en'` test and then perhaps just include a `404-en.php` template. That way the existing 404 mechanism still works. With the setup you have, the visitor is being redirected to a `200` page, so to a search engine it will appear your site has no 404s at all and everything is valid content!

Comment: Thanks, got the quote part :). Still learning... I have used your code -had to remove a ')' after false)) - then it worked but it keeps redirecting to the Dutch 404.  
I understand what you are saying about the WP 404 page, however I had problems with that one too, as far as the multilingual part was concerned. That's why I was experimenting with custom php.  But maybe better for the time being to use the standard Wordpress 404's  because SEO is more important that the nifty contents of that page...  Thanks for your help, appreciate it :).